# calculating average till reach NA value and then continue in R

Tags: r, list, mean

I want to calculate mean of elements of a column until NA value and then start again to calculate average for the rest elements and put all averages into a list.
my data is like this (taking mean of column V4 and put into list-of-means:

```
                     V1      V2      V3 V4
1                  chr1 3686375 3686400  6
2                  chr1 3686400 3686425  8
3 Next bedGraph section      NA      NA NA
4                  chr1 3840175 3840200  2
5                  chr1 3840200 3840225  3
6                  chr1 3840225 3840250  4
```

The list-of-means = `(7,3)`

Comment: please add a `dput(head(...))` of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data structure makes it hard to do such calculations. Create a `bedgraph` variable that acts to identify each separate `bedGraph` section, and then remove all those "dividing" rows from your data set. Then you can just use `aggregate` to calculate the `mean` for each section.

```
# Read in the data 
data=read.table(text='V1 V2 V3 V4 chr1 3686375    3686400 6  chr1 3686400    3686425 8  "Next bedGraph section"   NA     NA  NA chr1 3840175    3840200 2    chr1 3840200    3840225 3    chr1 3840225    3840250 4 ',head=TRUE)

# Make a bedgraph variable. 
data$bedgraph <- cumsum(data$V1 == 'Next bedGraph section') 
data <- data[data$V1!='Next bedGraph section', ]

# Alternatively, using the NA 
data$bedgraph <- cumsum(is.na(data$V2)) 
data <- data[!is.na(data$V2), ]

# Find the mean for each bedgraph section 
aggregate(V4~bedgraph, data, mean)
#   bedgraph V4
# 1        0  7
# 2        1  3
```

Comment: thanks for replying. the problem here is the text 'Next bedGraph section' is not a fix text. my actual data has different bedgraph names but all of them have NA value in column V2,V3,V4.

Comment: Note that I provided a suitable answer for that situation in the `# Alternatively, using the NA` section of the code. You can easily extend the code to check that all three columns are `NA` by using `cumsum(is.na(data$V2) & is.na(data$V3) & is.na(data$V4))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one row with a `NA`, just find the row number and then separate your data into two data frames.

Otherwise, if multiple rows contain `NA`, you can use package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)


index_of_na <- which(is.na(data$V2)) # find rows which contain na

number_in_each_block <- index_of_na - lag(index_of_na,1) # find number of rows in each block, including the terminating na
number_in_each_block[[1]] <- index_of_na[[1]] # set the size of first block to the first entry in index_of_na
number_in_each_block[[length(number_in_each_block) + 1]] <- nrow(data) - index_of_na[[length(index_of_na)]] # count the last block if it is not terminated by na


list_of_groups_in_data <- paste0("group_", seq_along(number_in_each_block)) # call the groups group_1, group_2, etc...

group_name <- rep(list_of_groups_in_data, number_in_each_block) # make a vector with the same number of rows as the data

data <- cbind(data, group_name) # now we have named each row with a group name.


#then use dplyr group_by to calculate the mean of each group 
data <-
    data %>%
    group_by(group_name) %>%
    mutate( mean_of_groups = mean(V4, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

Using

```
data=read.table(text='V1 V2 V3 V4 \n chr1 3686375    3686400 6 \n  chr1 3686400    3686425 8 \n  NextbedGraphsection   NA     NA  NA \n chr1 3840175    3840200 2   \n chr1 3840200    3840225 3 \n    chr1 3840225    3840250 4',head=TRUE, sep="")
```

We obtain:

```
> print(data)
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
Groups: group_name

                   V1      V2      V3 V4 group_name mean_of_groups
1                chr1 3686375 3686400  6    group_1              7
2                chr1 3686400 3686425  8    group_1              7
3 NextbedGraphsection      NA      NA NA    group_1              7
4                chr1 3840175 3840200  2    group_2              3
5                chr1 3840200 3840225  3    group_2              3
6                chr1 3840225 3840250  4    group_2              3
```

> could you tell me how to put the column 'mean_of_groups' into a new matrix with exclusion of repeat elements

Use `dplyr::summarise` instead of `mutate` in the last block of code:

```
data <-
    data %>%
    group_by(group_name) %>%
    summarise( mean_of_groups = mean(V4, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

which gives:

```
> data
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  group_name mean_of_groups
1    group_1              7
2    group_2              3
```

Comment: thank you @Alex , that works. could you tell me how to put the column 'mean_of_groups' into a new matrix with exclusion of repeat elements?